# Cassandra Table Definition out of Sync

Tags: cassandra

We have a problem with Cassandra. We have on table 'card_ix' and 3 different Cassandra Nodes.
If we execute the following INSERT statemtn on Node #1 and #2 everything works fine:

```
INSERT INTO card_ix(key,value1String,value2BigInt) VALUES('abc', 'value1', 1234);
```

When we execute that command on Node #3 the following error occurs:

```
Bad Request: Unknown identifier value2BigInt
```

Some time ago we changed the name from value2String to value2BigInt and changed the datatype accordingly. But for that we dropped the whole table and created a new one, but with the same table name.

The following command displays the same, correct result on all three nodes.

```
describe table card_ix;
```

A `SELECT * FROM card_ix;` results in the following error:

```
Failed to decode value '\x18\x94\xcaU\x19)\x12\x11' (for column 'value2String') as text: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

The table names displayed in the select statement are the old ones.

Does anybody has an idea what the problem is?

Comment: Did you try running nodetool repair on all the nodes?

Comment: Yes, but it did not work. We dropped the whole keyspace and created everything again. But it is important for us to understand why that error occured.

Comment: Can you check if the system clocks are all in sync?

Comment: They are all in sync.